# Fastest Method to Map from One Array to Another?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to map values from one array to another array of a different size, using a third array to provide the indices. I have successfully implemented this using a for loop, but I hoped to find a faster method using Numpy. So far, I have struggled to find anything that will work. The closest thing I can find is the numpy.put(http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) function, but since I am mapping from a large array to a small array there will be many values with the same index. I want to sum these values (+= at the index), but the numpy.put function just overwrites the value at the specified index.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
# Create the arrays for this example
import numpy as np

lattice1 = np.zeros(20)
lattice2 = np.zeros(20)

index = [0,4,7,8,9]*40

data = np.array(range(200))

# Make a for-loop to move the data onto the correct position of the lattice
counter=0
for item in data:
    lattice1[index[counter]]+=item
    counter+=1

# Trying to find a faster implementation using Numpy
np.put(lattice2,index,data)
```

and the output (print statements excluded from code above for ease of viewing):

> lattice1 :
>
> > > [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 
> > >       0.
> > >         0.  0.]
>
> index:
>
> > > [0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7,
> > >       8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0,
> > >       4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8,
> > >       9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4,
> > >       7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9,
> > >       0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7,
> > >       8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0,
> > >       4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8,
> > >       9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 8, 9]
>
> data:
>
> > > [  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16 
> > >       17   18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33 
> > >       34  35   36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50 
> > >       51  52  53   54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67 
> > >       68  69  70  71   72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84 
> > >       85  86  87  88  89   90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101
> > >       102 103 104 105 106 107  108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118
> > >       119 120 121 122 123 124 125  126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135
> > >       136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143  144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152
> > >       153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161  162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169
> > >       170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179  180 181 182 183 184 185 186
> > >       187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197  198 199]
>
> for loop accumulates data with same index on the correct lattice
>   point:
>
> > > [ 3900.     0.     0.     0.  3940.     0.     0.  3980. 
> > >       4020.  4060.
> > >            0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]
>
> output from numpy.put has overwritten values with same indices:
>
> > > [ 195.    0.    0.    0.  196.    0.    0.  197.  198.  199.    0.
> > >       0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]

My motivation is to speed up this process, as this for loop is significantly slower than the rest of my code (that I was able to use Numpy for). The arrays I'm operating on are on the order of 6,000,000 elements, and I have to run this over hundreds of arrays. Thus, a small increase in speed (5-fold?) would more than justify the effort.

Perhaps I'm stuck on the wrong solution and there is a better workaround, and if all else fails I can stick with the for loop. Nonetheless, any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: IIUC, I think this is a duplicate of lots of "groupby"-like questions for numpy (see bincount and the ufunc.at).  In your case, you could try `np.add.at(lattice2, index, data)` (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html)).  If this is what you're after, we can close as a dup.

Comment: @DSM `np.add.at(lattice2, index, data)` appears to be exactly what the OP needs.  It gives the same result as `lattice1`.  Do you have a specific question in mind that this one duplicates?

Comment: @DSM Yep, that is it! Thanks! I'll close the question down if it's a duplicate...I am still new enough that I guess I didn't search for the right keywords.